# Change static table to dynamic using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I'm having a JSON that's a parent-child structure and I'm displaying it in a table which expands on click of rows, showing its child elements.

The table works fine with static data.

I'm trying to make it dynamic with the below JSON using angular `ng-repeat` but
stuck in the middle as I'm unable to repeat child elements using `<tr>`

Please find the plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LaTo84?p=preview)
**JSON:**

{

```
  "fruit": [
    {
      "fruitName": "All",
      "season": [
        {
          "seasonName": "All",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 200
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 200
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Sept",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Oct",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "fruitName": "Orange",
      "season": [
        {
          "seasonName": "All",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Sept",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Oct",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "fruitName": "Grapes",
      "season": [
        {
          "seasonName": "All",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Sept",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seasonName": "Oct",
          "yearValues": [
            {
              "year": 2017,
              "value": 50
            },
            {
              "year": 2018,
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
        <tbody>
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".order11" ng-repeat="item in result.fruit">
                <td>{{item.fruitName}}</td>
                <td>All</td>
                <td>{{getValue(item, '2017');}}</td>
                <td>{{getValue(item, '2018');}}</td>
                <td>{{getValue(item, '2017') + getValue(item, '2018');}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="collapse order11">
                <td></td>
                <td>Sept</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>100 </td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="collapse order11">
                <td></td>
                <td>Oct</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>100 </td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>                        
        </tbody>
```

with getValue defined in your controller as:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.result = ...

    $scope.getValue = function(fruitItem, year) {
      var res = fruitItem.season[0].yearValues.filter(function(yearValues) {
        return yearValues["year"] == year;
      });
      return res[0].value;
    }
});
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/det90wMs7PZCUaAbBojp?p=preview)'s a plunker.

Then if you need to do it for each season you just need to add a new parameter in getValue function